# Where to do data.map() in ReactJs component?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I need to visualize data from props.signalsData array with react-table library (this array stored in parent component state).

Item in this array looks like:

```
{
  signal: {
    name: 'Signal 1',
    type: 'input'
  }
}
```

So, I need map it at first:

```
const data = signalsData.map(siglalItem => siglalItem.signal);
```

But, I do not want do it in render method (creating an array everitime when rendor method calls is not the best solution in terms of performance?!).

Also I don't want to store it in state, because set props in state is anti-patern.

Array can be changed from other komponent.

What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is potentially a case of premature optimization. There's nothing wrong with having `map` in `render`, it's very fast if an array isn't big.

A state can be produced when a prop is received, `getDerivedStateFromProps` is intended for that:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps({ signalsData }) {
  return { signals: signalsData.map(...) };
}
```

This likely won't result in performance improvements because it's triggered on component updates, too.

In case only `signals` is used from `signalsData` in this component, this means that excessive data was provided to it and `signalsData.map(...)` should occur in parent component.

Answer (score 0):

Use React lifecycles.

```
OPTION 1
/* called before render */
componentWillMount() {
  const data = signalsData.map(siglalItem => siglalItem.signal);
}

OPTION 2
constructor(props) {
  super(proprs);
  this.state = {
    loaded: false;
  }
}
/* called after render */
componentDidMount() {
 const data = signalsData.map(siglalItem => siglalItem.signal);
 this.setState({ loaded: true });
}

render() {
  const {loaded} = this.state;
  return (
    lodaded && <div> ...YOUR TABLE COMPONENT... </div>
  );
}

OPTION 3 (best option)

Use redux.
```

Comment: OPTION 1 - use componentWillMount is UNSAFE.
OPTION 2 - it is ok. But then i need check if signalsData was changed in other lifecycle method

Comment: its true, option 1 is unsefe, I dont know it. So use option 2 and componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState). Thats reason why OPTION 3 is better, with dispatch detects automatically if data has changed